# ionic v4 Capacitor ios: how to serve IMG.src from localhost with WKWebView?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, wkwebview, capacitor

I'm trying to serve images from the filesystem of an `ios` app using `WKWebView`.

Using `cordova-plugin-photo-library`, I can get the `PHAsset.localIdentifier` and from there I can get the image as a base64 dataURL (or convert it to a BLOB). But loading 100 thumbnails from dataURLs is very slow.

when I use `cordova-plugin-camera` in my `ios` app, I get an image that is served over localhost while using `WKWebView`:

`http://localhost:8062/_capacitor_/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7FC7C2FB-41F2-47CC-AD5C-4A1B18C8D6D3/tmp/cdv_photo_018.jpg`

How can I do the same from `cordova-plugin-photo-library`, or what can I go to load/cache images faster?